# Headers in table centered

Tags: css, html-table

I want the headers of my table to be centered. Now they are centered but not in proportion. They all start in the middle of the table but they all align left while the center of the headers should be aligned.

```
    <table class="prijslijsttable">
<th>Gelaat (epilaties niet inbegrepen)</th>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Mini-verzorging (40 min)</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 42,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Aangepaste verzorging (1u15 min)</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 55,00</td></tr>
<tr><td> <i>Specifieke verzorgingen :</i></td> <td class="rl"></td> 
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Anti-rimpel</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 65,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Extra hydratie</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 60,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Verstevigend lift</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 75,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Flash lift</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 45,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Verzorging heren</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 55,00</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="prijslijsttable">
<th>Epilatie gelaat</th>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Wenkbrauwen</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 7,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Wenkbrauwen modeleren</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 8,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Bovenlip</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 10,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Kin</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 5,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Wangen</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 10,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Volledig gelaat</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 25,00</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="prijslijsttable">
<th>Epilatie lichaam</th>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Oksels</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 10,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Onderarmen / volledig</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 15,00 / &#8364; 18,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Onderbenen / volledig</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 17,00 / &#8364; 30,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Bikini</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 15,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Rug</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 25,00</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.prijslijsttable {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  width: 994px;
  text-align: left;
}

.prijslijsttable td {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #41495D;
}

.prijslijsttable th {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use your `<th>` like this: `<tr><th colspan=2>Title</th></tr>`

```css
.prijslijsttable {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  width: 994px;
  text-align: left;
}

.prijslijsttable td {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #41495D;
}

.prijslijsttable th {
  text-align: center;
  background: gold;
}

.rl {
text-align:right;  
}
```

```html
<table class="prijslijsttable">
<tr><th colspan=2>Gelaat (epilaties niet inbegrepen)</th></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Mini-verzorging (40 min)</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 42,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Aangepaste verzorging (1u15 min)</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 55,00</td></tr>
<tr><td> <i>Specifieke verzorgingen :</i></td> <td class="rl"></td> 
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Anti-rimpel</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 65,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Extra hydratie</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 60,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Verstevigend lift</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 75,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Flash lift</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 45,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Verzorging heren</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 55,00</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="prijslijsttable">
<tr><th colspan=2>Epilatie gelaat</th></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Wenkbrauwen</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 7,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Wenkbrauwen modeleren</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 8,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Bovenlip</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 10,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Kin</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 5,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Wangen</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 10,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Volledig gelaat</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 25,00</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="prijslijsttable">
<tr><th colspan=2>Epilatie lichaam</th></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Oksels</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 10,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Onderarmen / volledig</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 15,00 / &#8364; 18,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Onderbenen / volledig</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 17,00 / &#8364; 30,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Bikini</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 15,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Rug</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 25,00</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add colspan attribute to your th. This would be your complete code. I have added an additional css property of text-align right on right td to make it more presentable.

```
<table class="prijslijsttable">
    <tr><th colspan="2">Gelaat (epilaties niet inbegrepen)</th></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Mini-verzorging (40 min)</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 42,00</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Aangepaste verzorging (1u15 min)</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 55,00</td></tr>
    <tr><td> <i>Specifieke verzorgingen :</i></td> <td class="rl"></td> 
    <tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Anti-rimpel</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 65,00</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Extra hydratie</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 60,00</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Verstevigend lift</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 75,00</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Flash lift</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 45,00</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Verzorging heren</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 55,00</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="prijslijsttable">
    <tr><th colspan="2">Epilatie gelaat</th></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Wenkbrauwen</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 7,00</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Wenkbrauwen modeleren</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 8,00</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Bovenlip</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 10,00</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Kin</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 5,00</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Wangen</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 10,00</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Volledig gelaat</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 25,00</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="prijslijsttable">
    <tr><th colspan="2">Epilatie lichaam</th></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Oksels</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 10,00</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Onderarmen / volledig</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 15,00 / &#8364; 18,00</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Onderbenen / volledig</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 17,00 / &#8364; 30,00</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Bikini</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 15,00</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Rug</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 25,00</td></tr>
</table>


<style>
.prijslijsttable {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  width: 994px;
  text-align: left;
}
td.rl {
    text-align: right;
}
.prijslijsttable td {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #41495D;
}

.prijslijsttable th {
  text-align: center;
} 
</style>
```

Comment: do not forget to wrap `th` into a `tr` . - .  `th` can only be a direct child of a `tr` element

Comment: Edited my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you may use the attribute colspan, to fill entire tr or use a caption tag.

see : https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html

```css
caption, th {
  text-align:center;
  }
.prijslijsttable {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  width: 994px;
  text-align: left;
}

.prijslijsttable td {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #41495D;
}

.prijslijsttable th {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <table class="prijslijsttable">
<caption>Gelaat (epilaties niet inbegrepen)</caption>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Mini-verzorging (40 min)</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 42,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Aangepaste verzorging (1u15 min)</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 55,00</td></tr>
<tr><td> <i>Specifieke verzorgingen :</i></td> <td class="rl"></td> 
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Anti-rimpel</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 65,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Extra hydratie</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 60,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Verstevigend lift</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 75,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Flash lift</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 45,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Verzorging heren</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 55,00</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="prijslijsttable">
<tr><th colspan="2">Epilatie gelaat</th></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Wenkbrauwen</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 7,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Wenkbrauwen modeleren</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 8,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Bovenlip</td> <td class="rl">&#8364; 10,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Kin</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 5,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Wangen</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 10,00</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="check.gif" width="15px" height="15px" alt="check"> Volledig gelaat</td>  <td class="rl">&#8364; 25,00</td></tr>
</table>
```